# Encountered an error while running StatsExample in Netlogo 6

Tags: statistics, netlogo, linear-regression

To use STATS extension, I read the information about where to put the folder as stated here:

https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/extensions.html

I downloaded Stats-Extension-1.4.0 and put put the extension's folder containing all the jar files and stuff like that in the NetLogo / app/ extension folder. When I want to run STATSExample, it says "Netlogo encountered the following errors while trying to convert the model to the current version". The only option is "open unconverted model" that when it opens, there is an error saying that "can't find extension :stats". What is wrong with my installation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stats extension has been updated to work with NetLogo 6.0 and a new set of log-normal distribution primitives has been added.  The new version of the extension is 2.0.0 and is available on GitHub, https://github.com/cstaelin/Stats-Extension/releases.

Charles

Answer (score 1):

As per [the current documentation of the extension](https://github.com/cstaelin/Stats-Extension#installation):

> Note that the latest version of this extension was compiled against NetLogo 5.0.5.

The extension simply has not yet been upgraded to work with NetLogo 6.

Doing so will most likely require changes to the code of the extension, since [the NetLogo extension API has changed for version 6](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/6.0-Extension-and-Controlling-API-Transition-Guide).

I would suggest [opening an issue on the extension's GitHub repository](https://github.com/cstaelin/Stats-Extension/issues/new).

If you really need to use the stats extension in the very short term, you could always revert back to NetLogo 5.x.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will open an issue there. I need to do an ordinary linear least square regression using a csv file. By revert you mean, I can uninstall this version and install 5.x, but I should remember to copy what was placed in the extension folder to be able to run the previous codes when I install 6 again, right?

Comment: You don't have to uninstall NetLogo 6: you can have multiple versions of NetLogo installed on the same computer. You will have to install the extensions (e.g., the `stats` extension) separately for each version.

Comment: I am away until Monday, but I should be able to make the extension NetLogo 6 compatible within a few days of when I get back.

Comment: That's awesome Charles! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Charles. It will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Nicolas thanks. I did not know that. There is still a concern though. I want to use STATS for a code written in the 6th version, so switching to an older version would not help. Right?